# How to retrieve the IDs of Facebook pages (places) located in a specific location and liked by a user's friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know one solution would be to retrieve the IDs of places located in a specific location using the Facebook Graph API, to retrieve the IDs of all the Facebook pages liked by my friends and then to pick only the IDs of pages in the location that my friends liked (using the "social context" that enables me to know how many friends liked a page). But it doesn't sound like the best solution to me (it represents LOTS of data).

Another solution could be to imply dependencies between operations in the request using the `JSONPath` expression format (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) but as said in the documentation "for security reasons filter and script JSONPath constructs are not allowed in the JSONPath expression", which limits significantly the usefulness of this strategy.

So I tried to use Batch Requests:

```
curl \                                                                                  
    -F 'access_token=...' \
    -F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "name":"likes-ids", "relative_url":"me/friends?fields=likes{id}"}, {"method":"GET", "relative_url":"search?type=place&center=48.85,2.35&distance=1000&ids={result=likes-ids:$.data.*.likes.data.*.id}"}]'
```

There are 2 issues in each batch request:

1. Weirdly enough, "me/friends?fields=likes{id}" gets me some likes of
   some of my friends (I think it's possible to get all the likes of
   all my friends as friends_likes has been deprecated, correct me if
   I'm wrong)
2. Even for the user's friends' likes I manage to
   retrieve, I don't get anything from the second batch request.

NB: The user's friends shouldn't need to login on my app (meaning I don't have the `user_likes` permission for them).

I'd be grateful if anyone could help with some remarks or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the friend to grant the `user_likes`. You are probably using the Graph API Explorer so your friends might have been testing and granted the `user_likes` permission (thus why you see some and not all)

> A user access token with user_likes permission is required to see all pages liked **by that person.**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

Notice it doesn't say friends.

For the second part, are you sure the ids returned from the first part of the batch have ids for places? For each friend object, only 25 likes are returned, you aren't guaranteed that the likes you get are pages of type place.

Also `search?type=place&center=48.85,2.35&distance=1000&ids=`, I don't this does what you think it's supposed to do. `ids` seems to override the type,center and distance.

e.g. `search?type=place&center=48.85,2.35&distance=1000&ids=375093055847509`

is the same as

`search?ids=375093055847509`

Seems like a bug here or an intended behaviour that as along as ids is returned override every other parameter.

So overall no, this batch call will work, the results you are returning are incorrect for your desired outcome.

So the only way is indeed the initial plan you had *but* in any event the query will only work for friends who are using your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page.context/friends_who_like

> Only friends who use the requesting app will be returned.

Comment: Indeed. You confirmed what I thought. Among the 25 friends' likes returned, some of them are not pages of type place. And indeed, ids override the type, center and distance.